# Load balancer AWS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have some loadbalancer which works fine. It's configured like this.
The app is just running on 80 and redirected by the webserver to 443 and has a route 53 above
[image]

Now I tried totally the same but when I set my loadbalancer on the same values + wildcardcert I get:

```
Updating load balancer named: xx failed Reason: Listeners can't talk to InstancePort 80 with secure and insecure protocols at the same time (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 409;
```

What am I missing? Why is it working for the other apps?

Comment: If you're sending to instance port 80, you'll need to set the _Instance Protocol_ to HTTP. It's not expecting HTTPS on port 80.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your second listener should have HTTP protocol as instance protocol. Or you should use port 443 for instance protocol.

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me. I think it's almost a bug that Amazon defaults to instance port 80 with instance protocol HTTPS.

Comment: @Danger And it STILL does it!

Comment: And it STILL does this - Classic LBs seem to have been forgotten